# ByteBuddy creating enums with constructors

Tags: byte-buddy

Using ByteBuddy how can I create enum with constructors such as this one :

```
public enum EnumConstructorSample {
    STATE1(10),
    STATE2(15);
    public int count;
    EnumConstructorSample(int count){
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

I tried this code and it gives me error.

```
Class enumClass = new ByteBuddy().makeEnumeration("STATE1", "STATE2")
                .name("DynamicEnum")
                .defineConstructor(Visibility.PACKAGE_PRIVATE)
                .withParameters(int.class)
                .intercept(FixedValue.value(1))
                .make()
                .load(EnumWithConstructor.class.getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
                .getLoaded();
        System.out.println(enumClass.getDeclaredConstructors()[0]);
```

This is the Error and it is happening in enumClass.getDeclaredConstructors()

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Constructor must call super() or this() before return
Exception Details:
  Location:
    DynamicEnum.<init>(I)V @2: return
  Reason:
    Error exists in the bytecode
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 0457 b1                                

    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)
    at EnumWithConstructor.main(EnumWithConstructor.java:19)
```

Answer (score 0):

For constructors, it is required to invoke the super method within the constructor. For enumerations, you'd need to invoke the `Enum(String, int)` constructor. You can implement this using `MethodCall.invoke(...).onSuper()`.

If you wanted to achieve this, I'd recommend you to subclass `Enum` manually since you'd otherwise define multiple constructors for the enum you are creating where Byte Buddy would invoke its own enum constructor and the fields would all have its default value.

Rather, implement the method and return the value based on its name. You can for example use a `MethodDelegation` and then use a `@This Enum<?> val` injection where you switch over the name to return the correct value as if it was stored in a field.

Comment: Java does not allow for a class to extend `Enum`. By using `MethodCall.invoke(Enum.class.getConstructor(...)).with(...)` I was able to create a enumeration but then Java does not allow for `Enum`s to be constructed via reflection. Problem is ByteBuddy does not recognizes this new constructor and create the Enum instances as before. Is there a way that I invoke my interceptor after the normal Enum constructor has finished execution so I just initialize the fields ?

Comment: Yes, you can also define the fields and for example use a `TypeInitializer` or `LoadedTypeInitializer`.